# CentOS custom ISO installation - /dev/root does not exist

Tags: linux, centos

I am building a custom ISO for CentOS 7 and for now I am just intending for this to be an absolute minimal install (a proof of concept basically).

I am re-creating the ISO via using mkisofs.
The command I entered is:

```
Mkisofs –o custom.iso –b isolinux.bin –c boot.cat –no-emul-boot –V ‘CentOS’ –boot-load-size 4 –boot-info-table –R –J –v –T isolinux/
```

This successfully created the iso and allowed me to mount it in the optical drive of VirtualBox. Upon installation I am receiving an error within the rdsosreport.txt that says:

> localhost dracut-initqueue[581]: Warning: Could not boot.
>
> localhost dracut-initqueue[581]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist

So far I have:
copied .treeinfo, .discinfo into the root directory of where I am making the iso. Created subdirectory /isolinux with all the /isolinux data from the latest CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01 as well as the /images and /LiveOS directories. I have also copied over the repo .xml file into the root directory.

I have tried a multitude of kickstart files, but the current version I am using is ultra-minimalistic just to get this to work at some point.

```
install
cdrom
text
keyboard us
lang en_US.UTF-8
rootpw --iscrypted $6$XRIetvtFyLXRFVzZ$jX7xRxsN6M.DIqwJ9DQui9ytaqK3IAzauSqB4zeRNvMKJo6xCJQAk90XIaxh.SBn0IBtyZM7ZlHK8eSk55VnG0
timezone America/New_York --isUtc
clearpart --none --initlabel

%packages
@core
%end
```

My ks.cfg is located in isolinux/ks/ks.cfg and when I boot into the system I am running is `linux inst.ks=cdrom:/dev/cdrom:/ks/ks.cfg`

I'm a little lost on where to investigate further as all I am trying to do is load a very simple kickstart file to get Linux to do a one-button install. I don't necessarily need to be told, just to be pointed in the right direction as I've tried quite a few different kickstart configurations and have come up with the same error.

edit:
I have gotten this working by editing the isolinux.cfg file and changing the volume ID to my -V volume ID set in my mkisofs and then selecting this menu option when doing my installation.

```
append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS quiet inst.ks=cdrom:/dev/cdrom:/ks/ks.cfg
```

I have other errors within the iso that I'm investigating now due to the fact my kickstart file is so barren.

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/root` exists in the master filesystem and if the related device is not expected to be dynamically created at boot time, you may be a victim of a  `mkisofs` that is not the correct mkisofs and works not as expected.

I recommend to first check this:

`find isolinux/ -name root -ls`

to verify whether /dev/root is in the master and then call:

`isoinfo -i custom.iso -R -J -find -name root -ls`

to verify whether the ISO image contains /dev/root as well.

Comment: /root is not in the /isolinux directory on either the iso or the master. Guess I'm slightly confused where this would even come from, when I view the .iso for the stock CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503 there isn't a /root directory either.

Comment: Why do you look for /root when you are interested in /dev/root?

Comment: /dev/root isn't there either.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, any time you see `dracut` (like your `dracut-initqueue`) it means that you're in your `initrd`. The `initrd` is a small image that gets loaded into RAM that is responsible for mounting your `root` partition, then switches to it and calls `init`. My guess is that your `inst.stage2` specifically is what fixed your issue, it tells the `initrd` where to find the `root` partition (the partition labeled "CentOS").