# unable to install centos on my windows 10 laptop making it dual boot

Tags: linux, centos

After hearing the news that `CentOS 7` had been published, I decided to install it on my computer. I downloaded the ISO image from the CentOS official website (the one named CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso) and then burned it onto a USB drive by using a tool named `unetbootin-windows-625.exe`.

When I was installing CentOS, I faced some problem.

```
dracut-initqueue[556]: Warning: Could not boot.
dracut-initqueue[556]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist
```

[Warning Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB5rL.jpg)[image]

Comment: [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233379/centos-custom-iso-installation-dev-root-does-not-exist) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141515/centos-7-installation-failed) might help you.

Comment: The problem is most likely caused by the tool you used to copy the iso.

Comment: @JuliePelletier .... So can you pls guide me the step to install centos on windows. I am facing challenge in the installation process of Centos.

Comment: CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso is an old version. Not at all usable : Too old to get package updates ! ... Latest is 7.2.1511 :  http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/centos.org/7/isos/x86_64/ ... Suggest CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveKDE-1511.iso ( Or CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso ).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Centos-wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) :

> UNetbootin is probably the most popular "outside" method, has both Windows and Linux executables, and allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for a variety of Linux distributions. **This utility is no longer recommended for use as it fails to work with newer CentOS iso images.**

The Solution :

> Create a bootable USB key simply by installing the ISO file on the key using a program such as [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).